# Net Core 6 - can post Multi Params with FormUrlEncodedContent to web api

Tags: post, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

The Web API controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("validateUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> validateUser(string email, string password)
    {
        var identityUsr = await _userMgr.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if (await _userMgr.CheckPasswordAsync(identityUsr, password))
        {
            var issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"];
            var audience = _config["Jwt:Audience"];
            int addMinutes = (int)Convert.ChangeType(_config["Jwt:addMinutes"], typeof(int));
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
                audience: audience,
                issuer: issuer,
                //notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                //expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(addMinutes),
                signingCredentials: credentials

                );
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return Ok(stringToken);
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Sender information:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount")] AspNetUser aspNetUser)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44327");

                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "administrator@rapsosuites.com"));
                values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "Pn.14024284.Fm"));

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/userApi/validateUser", content);

                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                resultContent = resultContent + "//"; 
            }
        }
        return View(aspNetUser);
}
```

- I test with Postman and it works fine.
- I test with the browser and it fails.

I make a change to this line and sending the parameters in the URL works fine !

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("/userApi/validateUser?email=administrator@rapsosuites.com&password=Pn.14024284.Fm", content);
```

For any reason the content object is not working sending the parameters

Answer (score 0):

you can not use PostAsJsonAsync for FormUrlEncodedContent, try to use PostAsync

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var result = await client.PostAsync("/userApi/validateUser", content);
```

if you want to  use PostAsJsonAsync you need much more code

fix the code

```
 var values  = new 
{
        email= "administrator@rapsosuites.com",
        password="Pn.14024284.Fm"
};
var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/userApi/validateUser", values);
```

and fix action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> validateUser([FromBody] ViewModel model)
```

and create a class

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string email {get; set;}
  public  string password  {get; set;}
}
```